# How to get school informations by id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to find a way to get some information (address, geo-data and so on ) of an education institute by the id.
My current request: response the following object:

```
{
  "education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "110415448986654",
        "name": "BULME"
      },
      "type": "High School",
      "id": "587913304561851"
    },
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "114054375298355",
        "name": "HTL Bulme Graz-Gösting"
      },
      "type": "College",
      "id": "587913327895182"
    }
  ],
  "id": "769605149725998"
}
```

I see that here are IDs for the schools, but how can I use this to load some data about this institute?
I read a lot on the developers Facebook page but I can't find a solution.